# How do I get a visual debugger on Mac OS when I have no Xcode project?

Tags: c++, xcode, debugging, gdb

I am porting a project over to OS X.  I am finding GDB debugging in the console to be woefully insufficient and really need a visual debugger.  My project is built using Scons and as such, it sidesteps Xcode's IDE entirely.  This is acceptable until I need to fire up a visual debugger and step through my code.

Aside from generating and maintaining an Xcode project (to supplement all of the other platforms I have to support already), what can I do to get a visual debugger up and running on OS X?

This is for a C++ project.

Comment: Any reason why you aren't using a graphical front-end to gdb?

Comment: Recommend a good one for OS X and I'll take a look.

Comment: Isn't DDD there for OS X? It should be sufficient.

Comment: @daramarak DDD for OS X is extremely buggy, barely usable.

Answer (score 7):

Simple:

1. Start XCode
2. Click 'Run' in top menu
3. Choose attach to process, choose the process you want to debug

Make sure to compile with full debug of course ... which means using option `-ggdb`

Comment: This attaches a debugger, yes, but it doesn't mean I can open a project file (even with File->Open), go to a line and add a breakpoint.

I get a nice warning:
GDB Warning: No location found for "cl_game.cpp:711"

Comment: UPDATE: I stand corrected.  I changed from -g to -ggdb in Scons, but the final binary copy failed and I failed to notice that.  -ggdb must contain the full pathname to the source file (or something equally telling) because this works.

Comment: UPDATE 2: Now it isn't working again with other files in other directories.

Answer (score 4):

Xcode supports makefile projects - you can just drag all your source into a new legacy project template, set up the makefile command line, tell it where the executable lives, and you're in business.

Comment: This goes against what I said above about wanting to maintain an Xcode project file.  I do not need to maintain an Xcode file every time I add, remove or delete a source file in addition to Scons and Visual Studio.

Comment: Years later, I am doing a variation of this with Xcode 4.  I am using an "external build target" which shells out and runs Scons.

Comment: Years later again I am using Premake to generate native Xcode projects.

Answer (score 3):

If you are Emacs friendly then: `M-x gdb` will put you into "gud" mode.  This turns Emacs into a visual debugger.  This can be made to work with the new lldb too.

Answer (score 0):

You can try ddd

```
sudo port install ddd
```

ddd acts as a front end to gdb and has a nice GUI.  In my experience, ddd has been quite stable and useful on OS X.  I've mainly used it for debugging OpenFOAM C++ code.